# Present perfect vs past perfect vs past indefinite

Tags: tense

1.I am tempted by the sumptuous chocolate cake , but I can't eat as my doctor had advised me to watch my weight.

2.I am tempted by the sumptuous chocolate cake, but I can't eat as my doctor has advised me to watch my weight.

3.I am tempted by the sumptuous chocolate cake, but I can't eat as my doctor advised me to watch my weight.

Which one/s is/are correct?

Comment: Side note: you'd have to say "but I can't eat *it*" or "but I can't eat *any*".

Answer (score 1):

The past perfect is used when we want to establish the temporal relationship between two events, both of which happened in the past.

So the past perfect is not apt here. There is only one event in the past in your example sentence.

The simple past is used with an event that happened in the past, and the present perfect is used with an event that happened in the past *in terms of its implications for the present*.

Therefore, the present perfect is the best choice here because it makes *explicit* the relationship of the doctor's past orders to your not eating cake *now*.

The simple past leaves that relationship *implicit*. It is a good choice here, especially since there are other elements in the sentence which make that relationship explicit: "as", which means "because", and "but", which also establishes a logical relationship.

Answer (score 0):

1. *...doctor had advised me...* implies that this restriction is no longer in place.
2. *...doctor have advised me...* is the correct tense, but it should be the singular **has**, rather than the plural **have**.
3. *...doctor advised me...* is correct as written.

Comment: If the advice is no longer in place, then it shhould be said "advised".Isn't it?Can we say option 1 ?

Comment: No. You were 'advised' in the past, regardless of whether that advice is still in effect, or was removed at some point.